# Scrolling webpage using jquery onclick to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have form on html and submitting the form using below code

```
<div class="submit-clear">
<input  id="generate" type="submit"  name="script" value="create"/>
</div>
```

The form data will be displayed on a separate `div` at bottom of the hash tag page `#output`

output section div id is

```
<div id="output-main">

<-------output of the form data will be displayed here---->

</div>
```

Once the user submit the form, I need to scroll the webpage to the `<div id="output-main">` section to display the output.
After searching previous question, I got below solution, but its not working for me.Please help me here

```
$('#generate').click(function() {

   $.scrollTo($('#output-main'), 500);
});
```

EDIT:

I have to scroll the webpage after form submit.The webpage will refresh with data after formsubmit and it load the #ouput page with form output

Comment: Try `$.scrollTo('#output-main', 500);` instead.

Comment: @PiLHA         : I tried it,but not working

Comment: Chrome > Right click > Inspect Element > Console. Make sure you aren't getting any javascript errors because the answers you're getting do work.

Comment: @ Rick Calder   This is the error I am seeing `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you correctly included the scrollTo [library](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js)?
Are you sure you are not getting any js error elsewhere (this may break your code)?

here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8Cy7V/

```
$("#generate").click(function() {
    $.scrollTo( '#output-main', 800);
});
```

Comment: : scroll library was missing. I have added it.After form submission, it is scrolling initially to the `output-main` div but later it is going back to top.how can I stick it the output div ?

Comment: @acr that is a weird behave not related to this question. If my answer solved your problem please vote it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#generate').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#output-main").offset().top}, 500);
   }); 
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4Ka5/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#output-main").scrollTop($("#output-main")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Comment: @acr I have just added code block formatting to this answer, Ashish must tell you why is it not working. Have you tried suggestion made by PiLHA in the comments?

Answer (score -1):

Do you submit the form? I mean, does your page refreshes when submit is clicked? If yes, try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var item = $('#output-main');
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: item.offset().top});
});
```

Make sure jquery is included on this page. Of course, you have to check when do you want to execute the above code. You have to check if form is submitted only then the code should run instead of document ready state.

Comment: Yes. I have to do this scrolling after form submit.I tried above code,but not working

Comment: : Issue with this code is the page is loading to div `output-main` before and after form submission. I need to load it only after form submit. how can I do it ?